# Polarised light passing a parallel filter

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetic-radiation, polarization

If a polarised light of an intensity of $I_0$ passes through a parallel (to the light) filter, what would the intensity of the light be after passing through the filter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the filter (polarizer) is polarized in the same direction as the light then the intensity will stay the same. For example vertically polarized light will 100% transmit through a vertically orientated polarizer.

Comment: Any real world filter will have some attenuation, no?